# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la diferencia entre conjuntos, si en uno de ellos son string y en otro integers?

Tags: python, conjuntos

Quiero obtener la diferencia entre estos dos conjuntos:

```
A = set(['11', '10', '9'])
B = set([9, 10, 11])
```

Pero el problema es que el segundo set() lo obtengo sin las comillas simples. Este set() es el resultado de un for() que saca datos de una base de dato:

```
A= set(a[1] for row in Arow)
B= set(b[8] for row2 in Brow)
```

Entonces cuando quiero aplicar:

```
var = list(A-B)
var=list(A.difference(B))
```

obtengo como resultado la lista A completa porque no encuentra similitud ni diferencia con la lista B porque no contiene comillas.

Answer (score 3):

Para que los elementos sean considerados iguales (mismo hash) han de tener el mismo tipo (con algunas excepciones, ver al final de la respuesta). En tu caso, uno de los conjuntos contiene cadenas y el otro enteros, aunque ambos tenga el "mismo" valor, son objetos de diferente tipo y generan distinto hash:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = "1"
>>> a.__hash__()
1
>>> b.__hash__()
256011212135858291
```

Debes hacer un casting de los objetos de uno de los conjuntos para que ambos contengan elementos del mismo tipo y poder aplicar correctamente la diferencia de conjuntos.

Lo puedes hacer al construir los conjuntos al iterar sobre las filas:

```
A = {int(a[1]) for row in Arow}
```

o bien:

```
B = {str(b[8]) for row2 in Brow}
```

Dependiendo de que quieras hacer con esos datos en tu código te interesará una u otra. Ten en cuenta que para el primer caso todas las cadenas deben representar enteros o valores numéricos convertibles a `int`, en caso contrario tendrás una excepción.

Ejemplos reproducibles:

```
>>> Arow = ['11', '10', '9', '12']
>>> Brow = [9, 10, 11]
>>> A = {int(e) for e in Arow}
>>> B = {e for e in Brow}
>>> var = list(A-B)
>>> var
>>> [12]
```

---

```
>>> Arow = ['11', '10', '9', '12']
>>> Brow = [9, 10, 11]
>>> A = {e for e in Arow}
>>> B = {str(e) for e in B}
>>> var = list(A-B)
>>> var
['12']
```

No siempre dos tipos diferentes dan lugar a distintos hash, esto depende de como está implementada la generación de los hash. En la propia documentación se señala:

> **hash(object)**
>
> Return the hash value of the object (if it has one). Hash values are integers. They are used to quickly compare dictionary keys during a dictionary lookup. Numeric values that compare equal have the same hash value (even if they are of different types, as is the case for 1 and 1.0).

Traducción libre:

> Devuelve el valor hash del objeto (si tiene). **Los valores hash son enteros**. Se usan para comparar rápidamente claves de diccionario durante una búsqueda de diccionario. **Los valores numéricos que se comparan por igual tienen el mismo valor hash** (incluso si son de tipos diferentes, como es el caso de 1 y 1.0).